What did Bruce Metzger think on John 20:28 (the confession of Thomas)
I managed to find only this:

"Attention will first be given to certain Biblical statements which teach the true deity of Jesus Christ, but which are not given proper consideration by the sect. The passages will be quoted according to the Jehovah’s Witnesses’ own translation of the New Testament, The New World Translation.

The Apostle Thomas addressed the risen Lord Jesus Christ with a confession of his deity when he said, “My Master 12 and my God!” (John
20:28). If Jesus were not truly divine as God is divine, Thomas erred
seriously in thus adoring him as God. Furthermore, if his Apostle had
been in error, it is passing strange that Jesus made no effort to
correct him. In fact, Jesus is represented not only as accepting such
an open ascription of deity, 13 but as commending all those who share
Thomas’s faith (verse 29, “Jesus said to him: ‘Because you have seen
me have you believed? Happy are those who do not see and yet
believe.’”)".
("The Jegovah’s Witnesses and Jesus Christ: A Biblical
and Theological Appraisal", 1953.
https://bible-researcher.com/metzger.jw.html)


But this quote is very old. Can someone help me to find a newer one? Thank you in advance.

Bruce Metzger died 13 October 2007.  There may be quotes from him post 1953 but it seems unlikely he would have altered his theological position regarding how Thomas addressed Jesus.  In the absence of any repudiation of what he wrote in 1953, and given Metzger's authority on biblical translations and the errors in the New World Translation, then surely what he wrote then still holds true.

@Lesley, I also think it's still relevant, but his position of at least 80s-90s would be even more useful for my apologetic works. Thank you for answering

Would there be any merit in pursuing later writings by his peers?  For example, Aland, Barbara; et al. (2000). Greek New Testament. Deutsche Bibelgesellschaft. ISBN 978-3-438-05110-3.
Ehrman, Bart D. (2005). The Text of the New Testament: Its Transmission, Corruption, And Restoration (4th ed.). Oxford: Clarendon Press. ISBN 0-19-516122-X.

I’m looking for works of at least 80s, so that it would be strong argument for my position. And also unfortunately I failed to find a mention of John 20:28 there. But thank you very much @Lesley
